# breeze.js insert parent/child with identity

Tags: insert, breeze, identity

Simple parent/child scenario like Order and OrderLineItems.  I am inserting a new Order, the OrderID is an identity column (sql server).  I'm also inserting OrderLineItems in the same SaveChanges transaction.  I need to get the new OrderID into the OrderLineItems, but not sure how to do it.  I have the appropriate FK relationships setup properly.  When I save, I get an error that OrderID is a required field in OrderLineItems.

Will I have to split this out into 2 server calls?  First to insert the Order, which will return the OrderID.  And then another to insert the OrderLineItems?

Comment: if you create Order, Breeze will set ID to -1 or something like that (invalid in database, but client doesn't know that). Then you set `orderLineItems.orderId = order.id`. Both order and orderLineItems then have that same id, invalid in database, but valid on client. When doing `saveChanges`, breeze will handle it for you - go to server, save, database gives valid IDs. You never need to know database IDs on client really, it's just for saving data.

Comment: Thanks, its working now. I think I may have forgotten to explicitly set the orderLineItem.orderId.  I see why its needed.  In my mind I'm working with just a single order at a time, but Breeze doesn't know that.  There could be multiple orders in the save batch and it needs to know which lineitems go with which order.  thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Breeze documentation discusses this topic (key generation) at several points including but not limited to: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/save-changes, http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities and http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/add-new-entity.

The basic idea idea is that providing that your model and metadata are set up properly, breeze can assign a temporary id in place of the identity column for use in linking your order and orderlineitem entities prior to being saved.  As part of the save process, Breeze updates these temporary keys to their "real" key values and updates the local cache as well upon successful completion of the save.

Comment: I read those prior to my post and it's not quite what I'm looking for.  From what I read in the docs, this is the sequence: 1) Send a save for the Order.  2) Breeze gets the order ID back and does it's "fixup" automatically.  3) Send another save for the orderlineItems.  Thats 2 calls to the server and 2 seperate transactions.  I'm looking for a single call, single transaction solution if possible.

Comment: You do NOT need to do two saves. If your fks are set up properly everything will save properly within a single save operation.  I believe that the DocCode samples in the Breeze zip contain examples of this.